# Text area in my php contact form won't work (send)

Tags: php, textarea, phpmailer, contact-form

I've been trying this for a while now, following a few different tutorials and and forum threads. It seems like a simple but i just cannot get the any data from textarea. Input type "name" & "mail" is Ok, it's working. I'll paste my php coding and my form below. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
<section id="forma" >
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
          <form action="send.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_page">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
            <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail" required>
           <textarea name="comment" id="comment" style="margin: 0px 15px -33px 0px; width: 307px; height: 66px;"></textarea><br>
            <label class="uploadbutton">
            <div class="button" ></div>
            <div class='input'></div>
            <input type="file" name="file" onchange="this.previousSibling.previousSibling.innerHTML = this.value"/>
            </label>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn2"></button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Php

```
<?php
    require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['mail'];
    $text = $_POST['message'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    echo $comment;

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                     

    //$mail->isSMTP();                        
    //$mail->Host = '';
    //$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                           
    //$mail->Username = '';
    //$mail->Password = '';
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                        
    //$mail->Port = 587;

    $mail->setFrom('');
    $mail->addAddress('');  
    //$mail->addAddress('');         
    //$mail->addReplyTo('', 'Information');
    //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
    //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');   
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    if(isset($_FILES['file']))
      $mail->addAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);    // Optional name$mail->isHTML(true);                            
    $mail->Subject = '';
    $mail->Body    = '' .$name . ' ,' .$comment. '<br>: ' .$email.'<br>' .$text;
    $mail->AltBody = '';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    header('location: thank-you.html');
}

?>
```

JS

```
 <script>

     $ ('form').submit(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var data = new FormData();
 data.append('name', $(this).find('input[name=\'name\']').val());
data.append('phone', $(this).find('input[name=\'phone\']').val());
data.append('mail', $(this).find('input[name=\'mail\']').val());
data.append('comment',$('#comment').val());
 if($(this).attr('id') == 'form_page')
  data.append('file', $(this).find('input[name=\'file\']')[0].files[0])

        $.ajax({

          type: "POST",
          url: "send.php",
          data: data,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success: (function(data) {
       $(this).find("input").val("");
          $('#modal').modal('hide');
          $('#modal1').modal('show');
          $("form").trigger("reset");
          })



    });
       return false;
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Remove the `)` behind it, and try again

Comment: I did it, but still wont work

Comment: @MaryamSamee Can you echo out `$comment = $_POST['comment'];`

Comment: @MaryamSamee try put `form="comment"` in your ` <textarea> ` tag

Comment: @IbrahimHafiji same :(

Comment: so whats the exact problem ? is the email not sent or is comment empty ?

Comment: @MaryamSamee you need to echo out your `$comment` variable in your PHP form so we know if its empty or not. If its empty then its a problem  in the HTML and isn't being posted properly. If the `$comment` variable is NOT empty and contains data then we can investigate further. Please echo out the variable and paste the results in your question above.

Comment: @IbrahimHafiji If you please, can you write this code (need to echo out your $comment). I'm newbee in php and dk how to do it yet

Comment: @MaryamSamee Type this `echo $comment;` under `$comment = $_POST['comment'];`

Comment: @IbrahimHafiji comment is empty

Comment: Try to change id="comment" to something else like id="comment1"...may be it works..

Comment: @KhushbuVaghela it's not :(

Comment: did you use any javascript code?

Comment: @sunilwananje on the site? yes

Comment: can you please show it for this contact form?

Comment: @sunilwananje i forgot about it, answer upated

Comment: replace $(this).find('input[name=\'comment\']').val() with $('#comment').val() because you are using textarea input selector wont work for getting textarea

Comment: @sunilwananje now text that has been entered replaced to "undefined"

Comment: @MaryamSamee textarea id is comment or anything else?

Comment: @sunilwananje wow! it's working! it's working! I can't thank you enough, seriously. I added id and now it 's working. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MaryamSamee you are welcome! I am happy to help you...

Answer (score 0):

your fault is in php code:

replace:

```
$comment = $_POST['comment']);
```

with:

```
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
```

remove extra bracket

Answer (score 0):

replace $(this).find('input[name=\'comment\']').val() with $('#comment').val() in js file 
 because you are using textarea input selector which won't work for getting textarea value